# Stored procedures over SQL in the code, good idea?

Tags: best-practices, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the arguments against or for putting application logic in the database layer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2450/what-are-the-arguments-against-or-for-putting-application-logic-in-the-database)

Assuming I got over the problem of maintainability and debugging.
My assumption is it is better to have all my queries as stored procedures.
Am I missing any caveat?

Comment: Also see: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4706/efficency-of-stored-procedures-vs-raw-queries

Comment: also see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6246/2356